# common method to bind ListControl with DataTable

Tags: c#

Hi Greetings for the day..
I want to write a common method to bind data to any ListControl with a DataTable and i wrote the below code. but i am unable to execute when i placed the code in a class in app_code folder to access in all pages.

Please let me know the optimised way of coding and where to write these kind of methods in app_code class or in BAL(class library).

```
public void BindListControlWithDatatable(ListControl objListControl, DataTable dtDataTable, string dataTextField, string dataValueField, int displaySelect)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dtDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                objListControl.Items.Clear();
                objListControl.DataSource = dtDataTable;
                objListControl.DataTextField = dataTextField;
                objListControl.DataValueField = dataValueField;
                objListControl.DataBind();
                if (displaySelect == 1)
                {
                    objListControl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2010, whenever **App_Code** folder is created, the below changes occur:

```
1. myClass will have the namespace as "myNamespace.App_Code"
2. myClass properties --> Build Action --> Content (which will disable intellisense)
```

Not sure why like that, but I used to solve them by doing the below things:

```
1. Renaming "myNamespace.App_Code" to "myNamespace"
2. myClass properties --> Build Action --> Compile
```

In additional to above things,

Try setting your method's access specifier as `public` to access your common code. (Assuming you haven't done this)